# EF4 Update model from Database VistaDB issue

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, vistadb

Does VistaDB support 'Update model from Database' feature in EF4? I'm receiving this message:

```
" ... 'System.ArgumentNullException' 'Value Cannot be Null'
Parameter name: providerInvariantName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to open a ticket on the VistaDB site to get help with that since this site is for general purpose answers.  Anything specific to an application should go the vendor, especially errors.

To post publicly the latest RC of VS 2010 was not compatible with VistaDB prior to build 13.  VS is still very much changing things.  Hopefully the final release won't change from the RC too much.